# Gmail REST API Continous Monitoring

Tags: meteor, gmail-api

Is there any way for me to continuously monitor a gmail account not belonging to the client logging in.

Basically, my app will be associated with a gmail account which I want to continuously monitor. When specific data comes through the e-mail, I want to parse it and add it to a database which the users will have access too.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: You cannot monitor gmail api of a user but with Google Apps Email Audit API, you can download user's mailbox. check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/#managing_email_monitors

Comment: "a gmail account not belonging to the client logging in" and "my app wil be associated with a gmail account" seem at odds/confusing.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks Eric, It is a special use case.

Comment: Basically users are going to have devices which are configured to send e-mail messages to the applications e-mail account. ( I was going to simply create a gmail account for the app and hopefully be able to continously monitor it from the server using refresh tokens). The data sent from the these devices gets pulled from the e-mail account and added into a database. Anyone would then be able to log in and view the data which has been ingested from any device. Thanks again

Comment: I've currently written the web app to pull in e-mail messages from each user, but this requires each user to set up their device to send the e-mails to the user specific e-mail addresses. The issue with this approach is that the data for a users device will not be ingested into the database until a user actually logs into the app and clicks a button to ingest his messages. Hopefully this makes sense and please let me know if further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to watch for updates to a Gmail account you can just use the Gmail API's history.list() method to find updates since the last time the account was polled:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list

There's no way currently to watch an account (e.g. get notifications), just polling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see the comments I posted under the main topic for clarification of my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to solve the same problem. The approach I took was to to use the Google APIs to implement OAuth manually rather than using the built-in Meteor accounts. This entails managing the authorization code and access/refresh tokens. Then you can interact with Gmail using the REST API. For continuous monitoring, you can use Meteor.setInterval() to set up a basic polling mechanism but there are several packages that can do that for you. I have a project with some example code at  https://github.com/philcruz/meteor-gmail-example